How to provided multiple permission in bicep for accesspolicy
This is the bicep format for table access policy
resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'string'
  parent: resourceSymbolicName
  properties: {
    signedIdentifiers: [
      {
        accessPolicy: {
          expiryTime: 'string'
          permission: 'string'
          startTime: 'string'
        }
        id: 'string'
      }
    ]
  }
}




permission
List of abbreviated permissions. Supported permission values include 'r','a','u','d'
string (required)



so i need to give permission of read and update. but the expected vaule is string and i am not sure how to provide muliple access permission

There are very few official sample codes about this, I find an community one, it is about fileshares, but has the same pattern for tables
resource share 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'fileshare'
  parent: fileService
  properties: {
    shareQuota: 100 //This is GB
    enabledProtocols: 'SMB'
    signedIdentifiers: [
      {
        accessPolicy: {
          startTime: '2023-03-17T08:49:37.0000000Z'
          expiryTime: '2028-03-17T08:49:37.0000000Z'
          permission: 'rcl' //read, create, list
        }
        id: 'readcreatelist'
      }
    ]
  }
}


Just change the sample permission 'rcl' to 'raud'
https://github.com/LinkedInLearning/manage-storage-in-azure-4413556/blob/bfdfa83be5d6b0163167db47e663948c24db96c1/chapter-4/04_06/standard-storage.bicep#L132

but the order matters, you cannot shuffle the format it should always follow 'raud'

We can provide the string as permission: 'raud'
r - read
a - add
u - update
d - delete
